# Detecting Kontakt beacons while in background

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on an iOS application that makes use of Kontaktio beacons. In foreground mode, I put `beaconManager.startRangingBeacons(for: region)` in `func application(...)` which ranges beacons perfectly in foreground. Meanwhile, I would also like to know how to make the beacons ranging also work in background mode.

I already read through several StackOverflow posts. Then, at Info.plist, I set "Application does not run in background" to "No", and I also added `<string>bluetooth-central</string>` and `<string>location</string>` under  `UIBackgroundModes`. However, after adding these, my app will still stop ranging beacons in background mode.

```
Kontakt.setAPIKey("MY API KEY")

beaconManager = KTKBeaconManager(delegate: self)
beaconManager.requestLocationAlwaysAuthorization()

let region = KTKBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: UUID(uuidString: "my beacon region uuid")! as UUID, identifier: "region-identifer")
beaconManager.startMonitoring(for: region)
beaconManager.startRangingBeacons(in: region)
```

I put this block of code in `func applicationDidEnterBackground(...)`, which I copy/paste the same code (that will trigger the beacon ranging event) from `func application(...)` to `func applicationDidEnterBackground(...)`. I am not sure if that's the correct way to make ranging also occur in background or I miss something.